# How to change a function name in js by reference or directly

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I want to **change a function name** either directly or by reference.

Obviously a property change works when using objects (or arrays):

```
    let object_1 = { some: "thing" };

    let object_2;

    object_2 = object_1;

    object_2.some = "other";

    console.log(object_2.some); // "other"
    console.log(object_1.some); // "other"  --- because the change was translated to the object1

    ///// also

    let array_1 = [ "some", "thing" ];

    let array_2;

    array_2 = array_1;

    array_2[1] = "other";

    console.log(array_2[1]); // "other"
    console.log(array_1[1]); // "other"  --- because the change was translated to the array_1
```

However when trying to do the same **with functions it doesn't work**.

Is it then supposed to be the function.name an intrinsic property created by browser Javascript API when the html page is 'onboarded' into it, and being made *immutable*?

```
    let function_1 = function() { let a; return a = b + c; };

    let function_2;

    function_2 = function_1;

    console.log(function_1.name); // "function_1"

    console.log(function_2.name); // "function_1"

    function_2.name = "newname";

    console.log(function_2.name); // "function_1"    --- ???
    console.log(function_1.name); // "function_1"    --- this somehow makes sense (but it's opposite to what happens to objects and arrays)
```

Comment: why you want to change function name ?

Comment: a use case would be to invoke it as a different function in a method, at least for a copy of it (like function_2 in the scenario above) - instead of including it into something as let newfunction = () => function_2

Comment: @Nur I think it is useful to receive an answer why we can't change function names because probably that would help readers to better understand how JS works under the hood, in my opinion